# Flutter: Is there a way to animate widget position more than 3 position in 1 animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I understand there is AnimatedPositioned widget for implicit animation from point A to point B. However, is there a way to animate the change of position to 4 points as in :
Point A -> Point B -> Point C -> Point D?

Even I to create my own AnimationController, using explicit ways (eg: AnimatedBuilder), how can I use the same widget to move from start position to 3 other position in animated way (using Position coordinate)?Creating a Tween only allow a start position (begin) and an end position (end). There is no path.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations should help

Comment: see `TweenSequence` - the docs say: *"Enables creating an Animation whose value is defined by a sequence of Tweens.

Each TweenSequenceItem has a weight that defines its percentage of the animation's duration. Each tween defines the animation's value during the interval indicated by its weight."*

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken have you done this animation? i need same kind of animation.